# How to save and handle tweets saved as JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am a Python newbie and I am writing a piece of code to collect tweets from two neighbours, save them in JSON format and plot some data. Do you have any suggestion on how to extract the tweet date and time, or on ho how to count the number of tweets for a neighbour? In other words, what is the best way to isolate the different variable of a .txt with JSON data into something plottable?

Many thanks!

```
from twitter import *

import sys
import os.path
import simplejson as json
import tweepy
import csv

#log into Twitter
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'XXX'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'XXX'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXX'

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

#I consider A to be a 2km radius circle
result_A = t.search.tweets(query="kaffe",geocode="55.662610,12.604074,1.24mi",result_type='recent')
with open('data_A.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(result_A, outfile)

#Similarly, B is a 2km radius circle 
result_B = t.search.tweets(query="kaffe",geocode="55.694700,12.548283,1.24mi",result_type='recent')
with open('data_B.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(result_B, outfile)
```

Comment: You may need to provide an example tweet so we can assess its format

Comment: Why CSV? So that you can process it in Excel? (assuming you meant CSV not CVS and it was just a typo)

Comment: Hi Talvalin, here is file_A: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2684973/data_A.txt

Comment: Hi Erik, that was a mistake. If I understood well, what I want to do is to build an SQL database. I changed the text of the question accordingly.

Comment: You can plot with various tools directly from Python; you don't need an SQL database or an Excel/CSV file; you can e.g. plot directly from memory, or if you need SQL, just use SQLite3 which is built in to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more advanced spreadsheet functionality in Python, you might want to look into http://manns.github.io/pyspread/.

Also, SQLite3 comes built in as the `sqlite3` module: just create an in-memory DB and SQL away.

However, here are some examples on how to do basic stuff in pure Python:

```
import json
import urllib
from datetime import datetime

data = urllib.urlopen('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2684973/data_A.txt').read()
data = json.loads(data)

tweets = data['statuses']

def parse_created(timestamp):
    _, m, d, t, _, y = timestamp.split(' ')
    return datetime.strptime('%s %s %s %s' % (m, d, t, y), '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

tweets_data = [(x['user']['name'], x['text'], parse_created(x['created_at']))
               for x in tweets]
```

`tweets_data` now contains a "table" of those columns, if you need it in such format (e.g. for plotting); or:

```
erik_tweets = [x for x in tweets
               if x['user']['name'] == 'Erik Allik']
```

or:

```
erik_tweets_before_today = [
    x for x in tweets
    if x['user']['name'] == 'Erik Allik'
    and x['created_at'].date() < datetime.date.today()
]
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the best way to convert time in a format I can plot? Now if I print tweets_data[2] I get datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 2, 7, 41, 35)

Comment: That's a `datetime` object; if you want to convert it to a string, use the `strftime` method: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Great! One last thing: how can I access the time column in tweets_data? If I type print tweets_data[:,2] I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple".

Comment: So why did you type `[:,2]` then? what do you thought it meant when  you typed it? In general, even though I know you'd like quick and effortless solutions, I simply recommend learning Python; here's a start: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Comment: @albus_c: also, Python has a plethora of data processing and even spreadsheet libraries/tools available: [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org), [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org), [Pandas](http://www.numpy.org), [pyspread](http://manns.github.io/pyspread/), and probably others; for plotting, take a look at for example [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org).

Comment: Thanks heaps. Matplotlib did the job!